# How do I print out a totally raw HTTP request/response with Werkzeug?

Tags: python, http, werkzeug

When using Insomnia or CURL or pretty much any other command line tool or program you can print out an HTTP request/response interaction in a easily readable text format something like this:

```
> POST /some_url HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: insomnia/2021.6.0
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 242

{
  "some_data": 123
}


< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 46
```

How can I get that with Werkzeug? If you're going to answer "Oh yeah just use `request.headers`", etc, listing all the properties of the request or response, you can stop right there, because that's not what I'm looking for.

I specifically want a simple function that just gives me the **raw** request data that went out or came in (if a webhook) and the **raw** response data. Or maybe one function for the request and one for the response.

For example, the Python `requests` library has a function in an external `requests-toolbelt` collection of utilities to do this which you can take a look at [here](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumputils.html#requests_toolbelt.utils.dump.dump_all). The result is a byte array which you can `.decode("utf-8")` to a string, resulting in pretty much the exact format as in the example above.

---

**Edit:** To add a touch more clarification, I know I can get something very similar with a format string like the following:

```py
f"{r.method} {r.full_path}\n{r.headers}{r.data.decode('utf-8')}"
```

But I don't know if that conforms to whatever standard an actual HTTP request is supposed to conform to, I know for sure it isn't the raw actual request, and I have no idea what sort of edge cases might cause this to be insufficient.

Comment: I found that the "standard" I'm looking for is right [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) for the request and [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html) for the response. Why is it so hard to see the request/response in this format in Python?